# Как сделать redirect в codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Как сделать чтобы после выполнения функции контроллером происходил редирект(как правильно прописать перенаправление к локальному URI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй параметр позволяет вам выбрать между методом "location" (по–умолчанию) и методом "refresh". Метод location быстрее, но он иногда вызывает проблемы на серверах Windows. Пример:

```
if ($logged_in == FALSE)
```

{
     redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
}